# Deserialize into an object that extends List<T>

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Using

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
```

the following deserializes my JSON array correctly:

```
public List<PrintJobTranslation> Translations
```

and the following doesn't:

```
public PrintJobTranslations Translations
```

with

```
public class PrintJobTranslations : List<PrintJobTranslation>
{
    public string GetTranslation(string Key, string defaultValue)
    {
        var translation = this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == Key);
        if (translation == null) return defaultValue;
        return translation.Translation;
    }
}
```

It throws the error:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object] ist kein Wert des Typs Print.printJob.PrintJobTranslation und kann in dieser generischen Sammlung nicht verwendet werden. Parametername: value

I did not find an exact translation, but should be something like this in English:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object] is not a value of type Print.printJob.PrintJobTranslation and cannot be used in the generic collection. Parameter name: value

How can I get the JSON to deserialize correctly?

Comment: I'd attempt to do it with `NewtonSoft.Json`. Not even Microsoft recommends using `JavascriptSerializer`

Comment: *Don't* use the deprecated JavaScriptSerializer. Even ASP.NET Web API uses Json.NET. The code you posted doesn't deserialize anything anyway. The error itself refers to a *dictionary*, when you show a List<T>. Where is the input, the deserialization code and the *full* exception, including its call stack? You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I may not add an external dependency to this DLL. Is NewtonSoft.Json available on all installs of .NET, and how to make sure the correct version is used? We always deliver the correct version in products we use it in.

Comment: If you had posted full example (actual json, PrintJobTranslation definition, how you deserialize) - it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Looks like this may be a bug or limitation in `JavaScriptSerializer`, see [c# Deserialize JSON list of object error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5096272/3744182) which reported a similar problem in 2011; the accepted answer is to just use a `List<T>` for deserialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to side step this completely would be to *not do that* - your method looks fine as an "extension method", so it'll *work like* an instance method, but without actually having to subclass anything:

```
public static class PrintJobTranslationExtensions
{
    public static string GetTranslation(
        this List<PrintJobTranslation> list, string Key, string defaultValue)
    {
        var translation = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == Key);
        if (translation == null) return defaultValue;
        return translation.Translation;
    }
}
```

and just use `List<PrintJobTranslation>` in your code.

Comment: Isn't it also discouraged to inherit from `List<>`?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy yes :) which is why I'm suggesting not doing that :)